# Is volatile really not useful in concurrent programming?

Tags: c, multithreading

According to Linux documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt) volatile is never useful in concurrent programming aspects.
I agree it's true if you stick to C11 standard. The standard literally forbids modyfing a memory location in point where the abstract machine is not touching it, however it is not the case in C89 and C99. A compiler conforming to C89/C99 is free to optimize the code by adding some "invented" stores to a shared variable in a point where nothing is being done with the variable in the C code (so it's outside a critical section). So the only way to correctly synchronize inter-thread data is to mark all shared data as volatile and in addition apply a lock or mutex. Why Linux developers are ignoring this point?

Note from C11, which is not present in C89 and C99:
*NOTE 13 Compiler transformations that introduce assignments to a potentially shared memory location that would not be modified by the abstract machine are generally precluded by this standard, since such an assignment might overwrite another assignment by a different thread in cases in which an abstract machine execution would not have encountered a data race. This includes implementations of data member assignment that overwrite adjacent members in separate memory locations. We also generally preclude reordering of atomic loads in cases in which the atomics in question may alias, since this may violate the "visible sequence" rules.*

Comment: Yeah, that's why the new memory model is a major improvement in C11 and C++11. There's indeed a urgent need for that, for compiler optimizations are breaking code (hacks) that "seemed to work" very hard and very quickly. So yes it was a hole in pre-C11.

Comment: The remarks about `volatile` probably predates C11. The main compiler that is used for Linux, gcc, only claims conformance with C11 for very recent versions. Also have in mind that for pre-C11, C had not even a model of concurrency with threads, so one could not argue within the context of the language about it.

Comment: Your argument seems to be "there is no way to write concurrent programs in c99, but volatile looks like it might do what I want, so it must" which is patently untrue (there simply is no way to do that). the only way to write correct multi-threaded code in c99 is to rely on implementation defined things like memory order for specific library calls like lock. In any case Volatile is as useless in c99 as it is in c11 for concurrent code

Comment: @Voo I don't think what you wrote is my argument. What I try to say is that for shared data you need two things: 1) ordering 2) guarantee that the data is not touched where abstract machine is not touching it. In C11 you have atomics for 1) and the standard generally requires point 2). In pre C11 world you can have 1) with compiler intrinsics but what about 2)? It's not guaranteed in general, but volatile can give you 2), so why not use it?

Comment: @mm You need ordering guarantees, atomicity and avoiding of rewriting data. Since standard volatile only gives you the last one it's pointless. There might be some specific compilers that give volatile additional guarantees (MSVC) but that has nothing to do with the standard. gcc's `__sync` builtins  for example also allow you to write implementation specific valid concurrent code and you don't need volatile there.

Comment: @Voo Please note that I have written "So the only way to correctly synchronize inter-thread data is to mark all shared data as volatile and **in addition** apply a lock or mutex." I have never claimed that volatile can be used as a synchronization mechanism alone. A propelry implemented (platform-dependent) lock or mutex gives you ordering guarantees and atomicity but what about rewriting data?

Comment: @mm We're relying on implementation defined behavior at that point already, so you can add "the compiler is not going to introduce superfluous writes after the memory barrier as long as the data you're writing is properly aligned" to the list. That's actually a really weak requirement - adding these writes would have no purpose whatsoever and you can generally expect production worthy compilers to not introduce superfluous code themselves.

Comment: @Voo Ok, then you mean the absence of rewriting data is provided by the presence of memory barriers, correct? If I understand you correctly you are saying that memory barriers would have no sense otherwise, so there is no reason to additionally mark the shared data as volatile, correct?

Comment: @mm Yep. Basically the existence of a memory barrier disallows all those situations where producing additional writes would help performance. Now if your data is not aligned correctly or you're reading/writing anything below the word size of the processor (only a problem for Alphas that didn't allow read/writes of byte sized data) you might still run into problems, but if you don't do that you should be as fine as you can be when relying on poorly specified implementation defined behavior... C11 was really a godsend for concurrent programming - particularly lockless things.